# Fix an object to screen in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I want to do an FPS camera for a game developed in openGL/glut. I want to see the same part of the gun always. So, I want to fix my gun to the screen, and when my camera changes, my gun changes too. The problem arise when my camera rotates. There is a point where a I lost my gun and I cannot see it. I have one class `GunCamera`

I have tried to set the gun the same rotation as the camera and almost the same position as it. But it fails when I rotate. I have the class `GunCamera`like this:

```
class GunCamera : public Camara
{
 Solido *s;
public:
void setSolido(Solido *s) { this->s = s; }
Solido *getSolido() { return s; }
GunCamera(double x = 0, double y = 1.65, double z = 0) :Camara(x, y, z) {}
void update(double dt) {
    //Transform to radians
    double ry = rot2rad(getRot().getY());
    Vector3D vel = { -sin(ry),0,cos(ry) };
    setPos(getPos() - vel * dt);
}
void render() {
    glRotatef(getRot().getX(), 1, 0, 0);
    glRotatef(getRot().getY(), 0, 1, 0);
    glRotatef(getRot().getZ(), 0, 0, 1);
    glTranslatef(-getPos().getX(), -getPos().getY(), -getPos().getZ());
    s->setRot(Vector3D(this->getRot().getX(), -this->getRot().getY(), this->getRot().getZ()));
    s->setPos(Vector3D(this->getPos().getX(), this->getPos().getY() - 3.5, this->getPos().getZ() + 5));

}
};
```

Error appears in render method.

Comment: While _conceptually_ the gun travels with you as you move about, in _practice_ you can just render your gun with the default transformation (ie. close to or at the origin, pointing in the negative Z direction).

Comment: Sorry, but I have not understood what you've said.

Comment: What he means is you can first render the gun with the camera in its default orientation, *then* transform the camera and render everything else. This way you won't have to move the gun with the player. (Also, please try avoid the [fixed function pipeline](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fixed_Function_Pipeline), it's 2019...)

Comment: The old-style OpenGL API you are using has an internal transformation matrix that is applied to every thing you render. `glRotatef` and `glTranslatef` change that matrix so your object appears rotated or translated. If you render your gun with the _default_ transformation matrix  (or something close to it), it will appear in the right place without synchronizing with the player position and rotation.

Comment: Sorry, but I still do not understand what I have to do.

Comment: Instead of rotating, drawing, then rotating back and drawing the camera, draw the camera with a clean matrix stack. It's as simple as it gets.

Comment: Moral of the story is that what you are trying to do isn't particularly complex, and you should try to get a stronger understanding of opengl fundamentals. 3D graphics isn't a trivial subject, and you may want to get a little bit of a stronger background in how things work, instead of trying to hack things together. Also as @meowgoesthedog pointed out, if you are serious about learning some 3d graphics, consider learning modern opengl. its really powerful and can be a lot of fun to learn.

Comment: Thank you guys, but it is the University who makes me use this version of OpenGL. I would prefer to use a modern one, but they obligate me to use this. Thank you all for your help.